# Trigger - Update record after class call.

Tags: trigger

Ok, for the life of me I am being thick today and cannot figure out how to get the original record to update itself. I am trying to do this in a bulkified method but every time I try to update the original record I get a "...record is read only.." type error.

What i want to do is uncheck the checkbox field, which is used as a trigger filter, after the trigger operations are finished. The field I am trying to uncheck for all records submitted to trigger is Recalc_Benefit_Grand_Totals__c.

Any suggestions on how to do this in a bulkified method after the operation below finishes?

FYI, the future call notes below are out of date. The Apex Class runs real time but due to the difficulty in changing deployed class names I just left it named the same.

```
trigger Employee on Employees__c (after update) {

    if (trigger.isUpdate) {
        for( Employees__c e : Trigger.new ){

            if( Trigger.oldMap.get( e.Id ).Recalc_Benefit_Grand_Totals__c == FALSE && 
               Trigger.newMap.get( e.Id ).Recalc_Benefit_Grand_Totals__c == TRUE)
            {

                //Create set for future call. 
                Set<Id> empIds = new Set<Id>();

                for(Employees__c emp:trigger.new){
                    if(!empIds.contains(emp.Id)){
                        empIds.add(emp.Id);
                    }                    
                }

                for(Employees__c empOld:trigger.old){
                    if(!empIds.contains(empOld.Id)){
                        empIds.add(empOld.Id);
                    }
                }

                if(empIds.size()>0){
                    EmpBenSummaries_future.generateSummaries(empIds);
                }

            }//End for each checkbox checked record
        }//end for each employee record
    }// End if trigger.isUpdate 
}//End trigger
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming all you are doing is updating a checkbox in your other class, simply Change to a **BEFORE UPDATE** trigger.

Doing this will allow you to modify the records in the trigger directly without having to perform a DML

```
trigger Employee on Employees__c (before update) {

    if (trigger.isUpdate) {
        for( Employees__c e : Trigger.new ){

            if( Trigger.oldMap.get( e.Id ).Recalc_Benefit_Grand_Totals__c == FALSE && 
               Trigger.newMap.get( e.Id ).Recalc_Benefit_Grand_Totals__c == TRUE)
            {

                //Create set for future call. 
                Set<Id> empIds = new Set<Id>();

                for(Employees__c emp:trigger.new){
                    if(!empIds.contains(emp.Id)){
                        empIds.add(emp.Id);
                    }                    
                }

                for(Employees__c empOld:trigger.old){
                    if(!empIds.contains(empOld.Id)){
                        empIds.add(empOld.Id);
                    }
                }

                if(empIds.size()>0){
                    EmpBenSummaries_future.generateSummaries(empIds);
                }

            }//End for each checkbox checked record
        }//end for each employee record
    }// End if trigger.isUpdate 
}//End trigger
```

A simple change, but you will have to evaluate your code to ensure the before update context does not cause any issues.

You may also be able to simply remove all of the additional class and simply update the field in the trigger instead of adding to the collection and processing in a separate class. Hard to say since you did not share what is going on in your class method

An Example:

```
trigger Employee on Employees__c (before update) {

    if (trigger.isUpdate) {
        for( Employees__c e : Trigger.new ){

            if( Trigger.oldMap.get( e.Id ).Recalc_Benefit_Grand_Totals__c == FALSE && 
               Trigger.newMap.get( e.Id ).Recalc_Benefit_Grand_Totals__c == TRUE)
            {
              //Your conditional evaluation here   
              e.CHECKBOXFIELD__c = [TRUE | FALSE];

        }//end for each employee record
    }// End if trigger.isUpdate 
}//End trigger
```

If you must stay in an *after update* context then the other answer would be the way to go but (see additionally comment) consumes more CPU time as everything gets processed and evaluated again. **Additionally** you will have to put in place some sort of **recursion** check to ensure the update does not cause a reentry into your code

Comment: Eric, thanks I realized that I was actually doing a lot of extra work for no reason. I started with some old code that I already had and after reading through a few times I realized I was overthinking what I was doing.

Comment: Just to be clear to the next reader. The answer given by Eric is the solution to the problem I posted here. I just realized I had a bunch of extra code as well in my trigger.